# cd into folders breaks/hangs zsh for minutes using Windows cmd, Powershell, Hyper, and Bash (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, zsh, cd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

To clarify which I've tried:

- Ubuntu bash
- Hyper
- Powershell
- Git bash
- cmd

I have installed Ubuntu bash on my Windows 10 PC. When I open `ubuntu.exe` up and I type `zsh` after the shell has started, my zsh shell starts up instead, as expected. This is perfectly fine and it does exactly what I want.

The problem: When I do the following sequences:

1. `cd`
2. `[TAB]`
3. `[ARROW KEYS]` (select an item)
4. `ENTER`

It should `cd` into that folder. And it does that, but it literally takes over a minute to do so. CTRL+C to cancel does not work.

Now that I'm in that folder, I can clear the console by typing `clear`, so that's what I do:

```
user@user-pc > /mnt/c/folder/otherfolder > GIT-REPO > clear
```

When I type `clear` and hit enter, it takes probably 30+ seconds before it clears the window.

I have tried a bunch of themes and a bunch of terminals/command prompts, but none of them work, not even the default one.

I've installed zsh and oh-my-zsh by doing these commands inside the Ubuntu bash shell:

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh | bash
```

Any idea why this odd behavior happens? It looks like it's zsh, because I can easily `cd` into other folders using all of the above terminals. The problem also happens if I simply `cd /mnt/c/folder/otherfolder/` with and without the trailing slash.

Comment: I just ran into the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As @Nick Cox said, zsh can be really slow when loading large git repo in windows.

I find the solution at https://winsmarts.com/oh-my-zsh-slow-in-big-git-repos-af9d10dd6681. You can delete git command on your theme configure which is in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes` .

Comment: related issue: [Slow git autocomplete with WSL2 and zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515114/slow-git-autocomplete-with-wsl2-and-zsh)

Answer (score 0):

Does it only happen in that particular folder? IME, large git repositories can be really slow on zsh+WSL even with the default prompt.