# Slow git autocomplete with WSL2 and zsh

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh, wsl-2

I recently switched from git bash on windows to using WSL2 almost exclusively.

The issue I am having is that my tab autocompletes for branches is insanely slow (in the seconds). Other autocomplete are fast, such as autocompleting git commands (git checko[TAB] would autocomplete to checkout without problem).

What can I do to isolate the problem or resolve ( less than 1 second to autocomplete) it?

Comment: Are your files under `/mnt/c` (or another Windows drive)?  if so, see if my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68972448/11810933) helps you out.

Comment: Ya this is what it was.

Comment: Is running `git for-each-ref --format='"%(refname)"' refs/heads` slow because that's what zsh uses? You can define your own `__git_branch_names()` function. If this is completion after `git checkout`, it completes more than just branch names and that could be where it gets slow. Is completion after `git switch` any better because that'll only be branches. Could be worth getting into the habit of using it instead for branch switching.

Comment: @okapi i just tried git switch and it doesn't suffer the same performance problems. I might need to just change my aliases for branch...or as a few ppl mentioned, roll my own

Comment: @okapi and `git for-each-ref --format='"%(refname)"' refs/heads` is not slow...all refs display quick

Comment: Completion after `git checkout` completes a number of other things: recent commits, tags, remote branches. It'd be useful to narrow down which is slow. You can disable them individually with the `tag-order` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to autocomplete branches, bash has to parse files from the `.git/refs` directory or `.git/packed-refs` file, where the branch/tag names are stored.

If your repo is stored on the windows partition, this might be the reason why it's slow, as the windows/linux filesystem interop is known to be slow as of now.

In order to speed up the branch-name autocomplete, you could move the repo to the linux partition. If that's not an option, you could write your own autocomplete script that avoids IO with the windows filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

`git config --global oh-my-zsh.hide-info 1`

Disable oh-my-zsh git prompt magic.

Root cause is WSL using the slow 9P protocol to access Windows drive.
ref.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/135962